# Can't type on form inputs (wordpress booked plugin)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm tired of looking for a solution for my problem and I need your help please.

I have a wordpess website with this plugin : "Booked - Appointment Booking for WordPress".

When I try to make an appointment, the text inputs are not working, and I can't enter values.

When I saved the page in my local, it works, can you help me please ?

website : http://lanoire.monpreprod.com/

[capture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbrkT.png)

[capture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oif4s.png)

Comment: The website link you provided is not loading at all.

Comment: Hi, can you check the link now ? thanks

Comment: it work too when i put the calendar directly in home page, but still not working on the fancybox.

Comment: probleme solved, it was an old version of fancybox jquary plugin